# Wrapper class for canvas context

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript-typings

Idea is to make a class that would extend given canvas context, provide additional methods and store some data (like canvas centre or colour pallet) but also allow access to contexts properties

**In plain JavaScript this works fine:**

```
class Board  {
  constructor(ctx) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Board.prototype, ctx)
  }

  drawHexagon(){
    //do the drawing
  }
}

let board = new Board(canvas.getContext("2d"))

board.fillStyle = "white" //accesses contexts property
board.drawHexagon() //uses own method
```

This seems like a hack, but a haven't figured out other way. Also typescript is unaware that Board extends provided context and complains when I try to access it's properties.

**I tried typing Board like this:**

```
class Board extends CanvasRenderingContext2D {
  constructor(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    super() 
    //typescript requires call to super if class extends something
    //but this creates a runtime error
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Board.prototype, ctx)
  }
}
```

**tried like this:**

```
//results in an error from typescript:
//Class 'Board' incorrectly implements interface 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'
class Board implements CanvasRenderingContext2D {
  constructor(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Board.prototype, ctx)
  }
}
```

And yes, I could just do it like this

```
class Board  {
  context: CanvasRenderingContext2D
  constructor(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    this.context = ctx
  }
}

let board = new Board(canvas.getContext("2d"))
board.context.beginPath() //here is how I would that access contexts property
```

But the goal is exactly to avoid it (if possible)

*I as usual got stuck thinking about one solution and not seeing others.*

What would be a proper way to implement this class?

Comment: You wrote "In plain JavaScript this works fine", but when I try in Chrome (version 90), `board.fillStyle = ...` gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

Comment: Strange, how did you even get that error? But there is a different problem with that example - setting fillStyle does so only for that board instance, I tested it yesterday and it seemed to work, now it doesn't and it baffles me

Comment: As far as I know, I added the least amount of code required to test what you wrote; if you have a working example in Javascript (which actually draws a shape to a canvas with some fillStyle), please edit the question to include it.